# Ephem not updating real time

Tags: python-3.x, pyephem

I have a program with a map on a canvas.  When I scroll over the map it displays on the screen the longitude and latitude of where the mouse pointer is located, updated realtime.  As well, when I move the mouse it show the sunrise, sunset, moonrise, moonset, and moon phase for where I am at on the screen.  Everything is working fine except ephem obviously doesn't update real time.

This is the ephem specific part of the code that is run everytime the mouse is moved.

```
self.maploc.lat, self.maploc.lon = str(py), str(px)
sr = str(self.maploc.next_rising(ephem.Sun()
ss = str(self.maploc.next_setting(ephem.Sun()))
snr = sr.split(' ')
sns = ss.split(' ')
self.maploc.lat, self.maploc.lon = str(py), str(px)
mr = str(self.maploc.next_rising(ephem.Moon()))
ms = str(self.maploc.next_setting(ephem.Moon()))
mn = ephem.Moon()
mn.compute(self.maploc)
mnr = mr.split(' ')
mns = ms.split(' ')
```

I would think running the mn.compute(self.maploc) would do a complete update of the map coordinates but it doesn't.  Granted yesterday as I started tinkering with this idea I noticed it didn't seem to be doing live updating with the sunrise times either.

How do I get real time updating or can I with ephem.

If I run the program the moon phase will always stay the same until I close out the program and restart the program.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reset the maploc’s date, otherwise its routines like `next_rising()` will probably just compute times based on the date it got when you created it.

```
from ephem import now
...
self.maploc.date = now()
```

That is how you can update the `maploc` to start thinking about calculations from a new date and time. Good luck!